# Issue using google-map polymer element multiple times in same page

Tags: google-maps, polymer, material-design, angular-material

We are trying use google-map element from Iron Elements.

```
<google-map latitude="37.77493" longitude="-122.41942" api-key="XXXXX" version="3.exp" libraries="places" >    </google-map>
```

We are trying to load it dynamic/via ajax load. We are facing the issue regarding load of maps api multiple times. We realized its same issue when we use multiple instances of google-map element in same page.

> You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page.
>   This may cause unexpected errors.

[image]

Is there a workaround from this issue?

Edit:

google-maps-api element states:

> Any number of components can use `<google-maps-api>` elements, and the
>   library will only be loaded once.

If this is happening, I hope we should not face multiple load issue.

Comment: It's worked fine for me in the past. Please elaborate on "We are trying to load it dynamic/via ajax load." And perhaps include more of a code sample.

Comment: I the google map element is part of html which is loaded via javascript. It loads multiple in part of page.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with the google maps component. There is a workaround: you have to define the same libraries attribute to each  element you use.

https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-streetview-pano/issues/15